# Organisation package.json on React Project

Tags: reactjs, vite, package.json, nodemon

I use vite to create my React project and I would like to know how to organise my package.json for my React project.

[image]

In folder "services" I have my connexion to MongoDB and my MERN stack. So what is the best : have only one package.json for "services" and the application or two files differents ?

And my next question is how I can run (npm run dev) in one command line on terminal if I have two files package.json or if I have one file with vite + nodemon to show the index file of my folder "services"

Thank you for your help